# Tracking time for function to run

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have 2 questions. One basic logistics and one "Why?!"

First!

```
high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();        
for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {a.prepend(i);}                           
high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();   
duration<double, milli> time_span = t2 - t1;                                

cout << "It took me " << time_span.count() << " XXXX to run this "
```

What is this returning exactly?  I *thought* it was seconds, but its telling me 4 seconds for a program that executes almost instantly.

Now, the big question. I'm trying to get the run time of a waft of functions, all running 1/10/100/10000/100000 times. Clearly it will get incrementally bigger.

But if I run one function by itself I get times like this instantaniously (Not in 5 seconds)..

```
Add at i
It took me 0.000471 seconds to run this 1 times.
It took me 0.005088 seconds to run this 10 times.
It took me 0.017778 seconds to run this 100 times.
It took me 0.151778 seconds to run this 1000 times.
It took me 1.25263 seconds to run this 10000 times.
It took me 3.97601 seconds to run this 100000 times.
```

If I run 2 or three other functions first it gives me this after 25 seconds.

```
Add at i
It took me 5.2e-05 seconds to run this 1 times.
It took me 0.000781 seconds to run this 10 times.
It took me 0.022803 seconds to run this 100 times.
It took me 2.15357 seconds to run this 1000 times.
It took me 205.209 seconds to run this 10000 times.
It took me 20848.9 seconds to run this 100000 times.
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: You see that `duration<double, milli>` type? You don't wonder what `milli` means in this context? Perhaps you should go through e.g. [this `std::chrono` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono)?

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm dumb... It was late, and I was getting odd runtimes. I assumed it was milli, but that didn't make sense. I eventually figured out why though.  Thank though.